# 'mail' not working in Script same way it is working from command line

Tags: shell, unix

The below line of code/command is working as expected if I run it from Unix terminal, but not if I include it in a script and run the script - exact same.

I am expecting the X-Priority to show the mail as high priority in Outlook.
If I run it from command line, I see the email is showing correctly as high priority and I see the file is attached and the body appear as supposed to.
However, if I write it a shell script and run the script, the mail come formatted as text and attachment is appended to the body of the email and the email is shown as normal in outlook.

Not sure what I am doing wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Shell Script

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Message Body" | mail -r "sender@mycom.com" -c "ccrecipient@mycom.com" -s "$(echo -e "Message Subject\nX-Priority: 1")" -a "logFile.log" "torecipient@mycom.com"
```

Command line

```
echo "Message Body" | mail -r "sender@mycom.com" -c "ccrecipient@mycom.com" -s "$(echo -e "Message Subject\nX-Priority: 1")" -a "logFile.log" "torecipient@mycom.com"
```

--

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question belongs to https://serverfault.com

Comment: Thanks, I asked the question there now. https://serverfault.com/questions/1123918/mail-not-working-in-script-same-way-it-is-working-from-command-line

Comment: Thanks to close this one

Comment: How do I close my question?

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?t=lm&q=how+to+close+my+own+question+stackoverflow&ia=web